# Is Elastic Search What I need?

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, asp.net-core

I am a little bit confused on how Elastic Search works so I am not sure if it is what I need or if something else would be better.

**What I am trying to achieve.**

I going to have SPA with a Asp.net Core Api and SQL Server database.

**Filtered Categories**

When a user comes to my site they will be able to search (ie Computer) and results will come back. On the side there will be filtering options like

```
Brand 
Apple (50)
Microsoft (100)

Ram 
2 GB ( 10)
4 GB ( 80)
```

First thing I need to calculate is those counts, as there maybe 1000+ results coming back I can't bring all the results back at once, so I may return 50 results at a time but those counts should be of all the matches in my database.

If they check 2GB then it should do another request and just get those 10 results back.

**Type Ahead**

I know this is supported by Elastic Seach

**Other Questions**

From my understanding, Elastic search is it's own database(nosql), I need to keep my SQL Server database, so how do I keep these 2 databases in sync?

In my example there some of the data will probably stored in JSON EAV for instance Ram would be stored as an JSON EAV as I will have many other products that might not be computers and have no ram at all. Will this cause problems with syncing?

Elastic Search seems to be it's own service that you call via a rest api, how do you secure it so only my applications can call it?

How do I deploy it to a server?

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question, yet a very broad one. Elastic would most definitely work in that scenario but probably not your best choice to get started.

For you MVP or v.1.0 I would just use a regular relational db (i.e. sql server) and then once you get into hundreds of thousands or millions users consider things like elastic, redis, etc.

For you other question, if you do choose elastic, you do not really have to use a relational db to mirror your data, but in reality you will most likely end up using one.

Bottom line, start simple with tools you are familiar with and once you are up and running you'll have plenty of opportunity to optimize as needed.

Comment: hmm you got a good point, Though not sure how to do type ahead with sqlserver/EF not how to search an EAV file. So I might be in the same boat but I may post a question on this and see how hard it is.

Comment: type ahead is not hard to do, you don't need elastic for that.

Comment: oh do you have an example on how to do it? From the past when I tried to do "autocomplete", my requests could not catch up with what the user was typing and it was a poor experience.

Comment: For performant [incremental search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incremental_search) try using [N-Gram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram).  Take a look at a [SQL Server implementation](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/33419.sql-server-implementation-of-n-gram-search-index.aspx).